# While still in an interviewing process, is an automated feedback request without an offer typically a sign of rejection?

Tags: hiring-process, hiring, feedback, rejection

I am in a hiring process.  I've had multiple interviews so far for the same position.  I typically hear from the hiring company every week or so with more follow-up interviews.

After the last interview, today I got an automatic email from their talent acquisition system asking for feedback about the recruiting process.

I've not gotten a formal rejection notice yet, much less a formal offer.

Just out of curiosity, when feedback is asked automatically via an email, about an interview and/or hiring process without getting a formal rejection nor offer, is this typically a sign that another candidate has been chosen for the position?

If it helps the company is in USA so thanksgiving might explain why haven't gotten any communication from them yet.

Best regards,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> when feedback is asked automatically via an email, about an interview
> and/or hiring process without getting a formal rejection nor offer, is
> this typically a sign that another candidate has been chosen for the
> position?

No. It's not a sign that another candidate has been chosen. And it's not a sign that you have been chosen.

It's a sign that their automated system is aggressive about asking for feedback, nothing more.

Comment: I agree with this answer. To kind of expand, I can personally attest that when I've been involved in the interview process, the automated emails sometimes get sent out before we've even formally discussed who we want for the role. It sort of makes sense too, to ask for feedback on the interview process before their opinion is influenced by whether they got the job or not!

Comment: Thank you Joe and @DoctorPenguin.  Makes sense.  Happy thanksgiving!

Comment: In this case, it was a sign that they had moved forward with another candidate. (shrug) :)